# Python - sorting a list of tuples

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, rgb

I have a sorting algorithm that works perfectly with lists of numbers. It sorts from lowest to highest. What I need is to modify the algorithm so that i can set a list of tuples as the argument.

```
def maxList(A): 
    return(max(num for num in A))
def obtainDigit(num, n): 
    return (num // 10 ** n) % 10
def linkLists(A): 
    lAux = [] 
    for sublist in A: 
        lAux.extend(sublist) 
    return(lAux)
def generateSublists(A, digit): 
    subListsAux = [[] for i in range(255)] 
    for num in A: 
        subListsAux[obtainDigit(num, digit)].append(num) 
    return(subListsAux)
def radixSort(A): 
    iterations = len(str(maxList(A))) 
    for digit in range(iterations): 
        sublists = generateSublists(A, digit) 
        A = linkLists(sublists) 
    return(A)
```

The list of tuples is actually a set of RGB values obtained from an image. Using PIL I can get the following data:
(100,100,100),(255,0,0),(200,200,200),(0,255,0)
After the sort, it should be:
(0,255,0),(100,100,100),(200,200,200),(255,0,0)
The algorithm compares the first digit of each number, and after sorting them by their first digit, it then compares the second one. And so on until the last digit. So, instead of comparing digits, it has to compare all the first numbers of the tuples, then the second ones, and so on.

Comment: I just saw how the sort attribute solves the problem. But, is there a way to modify the algorithm above so that it can solve the problem as well?
I really need to make it work with tuples.

Answer (score 4):

> [The algorithm] has to compare all the first numbers of the tuples, then the second ones, and so on.

In Python you can sort a list of tuples directly, and it behaves exactly as you describe:

```
>>> sorted([(100, 100, 100), (255, 0, 0), (200, 200, 200), (0, 255, 0)])
[(0, 255, 0), (100, 100, 100), (200, 200, 200), (255, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sorting on key which sorts lists in place. And also offers convenient way to sort tuples based on index of tuple elements.
i.e. `tup[0]` to sort on first tuple element
     `tup[1]` to sort on second and so on.

See [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) for details.

```
t =  [(100,100,100),(255,0,0),(200,200,200),(0,255,0) ]
>>> t.sort(key=lambda tup:tup[0])
>>> t
[(0, 255, 0), (100, 100, 100), (200, 200, 200), (255, 0, 0)]
>>>
```

Comment: This will fail for `t =  [(100,100,100),(255,0,0),(100,100,0),(200,200,200),(0,255,0) ]` as you only using one attribute

Comment: OP's requirement is not clear. I assumed he wanted only first element of tuple and also as reflected in his example. If he needs all the index elements of tuples then we can use method mentioned by you which I am aware of.

Answer (score -1):

You are basically looking for multiple attribute sort.

```
t =  [(100,100,100),(255,0,0),(100,100,0),(200,200,200),(0,255,0) ]

t1 = sorted(t, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2]))
```

or you can use

```
import operator
t.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(0, 1, 2))
```

Comment: Your lambda is just repackaging the input